wifi sticks to 2.4ghz and won't switch to 5ghz
My wifi devices stick to 2.4ghz and won't switch to 5ghz. I have a new Verizon FIOS router with 2.4ghz and 5ghz bands. When I move briefly to another room, all devices switch to the 2.4ghz band. I don't understand why the 2.4ghz band is incredibly slow even close to the router, but it is. I'll tackle that with Verizon FIOS support maybe.
Through this experience, I see that devices will switch when the power is too low for the wifi point that they are attached to. They will stick with a strong 2.4ghz signal even when the network is crazy slow and even the default setting is that 5ghz is preferred. Some devices let me change the setting to disable 2.4ghz, which is bad solution since several spots in my home are inaccessible to the 5ghz signal.
None of the devices do what I would think is the most sensible, which would be to try to connect the supposedly preferred 5ghz band periodically if not constantly. This way, when I leave the nether regions of my home and I am standing in front of my router, it would reconnect to the 5ghz band.
What are the best options out of this issue? Is this common for everyone? I have all types of devices, Windows Dell laptops, iPhones, Android phones, iPads, MS Surface. They all do the same thing.

5GHz is effected by walls more than 2.4GHz what material are the walls made out of?

5GHz is great for short range and nothing blocking. Different radio and antenna design may help the 5Ghz signals reach further. 2.4Ghz should still be plenty fast for most home network use and will work further away and through or around obstacles better. Don't look at the reported speed: actually test by transferring files, browsing the internet, etc.

This isn't easy to answer without site/hardware access. Ideally, you would dial back your 2.4G antennas, dial up your 5G, and add an access point where you need them.  If your 2.4G seems slow intermittently, take a look at the router settings. If it's set to automatically switch channels you might disable that. There are only 3 that don't overlap. Pick the best one for you and then stick with it. IF you are among other networks (neighbors) doing the same thing, the downtime during transitions may be pointless (let your neighbors' hop around instead).

If all your devices behaves similar, then the cause might be e.g. with the router or the surroundings.
Why not try to check if you can switch channel to use in the router, you might have a neighbor or a facility that use the same channels that you are using currently.
Many devices trying to access the same AP might also be a problem, this may well create congestion, i.e. "traffic jam".
Example Tool that allows to see signals and their strength:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pierwiastek.wifidata

Make sure your AP (wireless router) is using the exact same SSID (wireless network name), wireless security type, and wireless password for both bands.
If you split the SSIDs like "mynet" and "mynet_5GHz", client devices will not treat them as the same network and will not roam from one band to the other.
Even if the SSIDs were the same, if the wireless security type is different in even a subtle way, clients will treat them as separate networks. So maybe you thought you'd used, say, WPA3 Personal on both bands, but it turns out that on one band you'd also left WPA2 Personal available as an option, whereas on the other band you had not left WPA2 available as an option, that difference will cause clients to treat them as separate networks.
